# Add a view to a UITableViewCell's contentView when it is selected

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I am trying to add a new view with 5 buttons to a cell once it is [selected](https://img.skitch.com/20110223-mrushbkeunds4i74h8298e3tyw.jpg). I am trying to do this in 3 different ways. The first one is by checking if it is selected inside the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.

```
if (cell == nil ) {
//initial customizaton of cells
} else {
   if ([cell isSelected]) {
   //I would add the view to the cell's contentView here but it never enters this if even though the cell is still blue, I scrolled the table back and forth several times and the blue cell never evaluated here

   }
}
```

I have also tried to do it inside the following two methods:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I used `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get a reference to the cell and when I had that reference I tried adding the view inside the cell's contentView but it didn't seem to work(by "didn't work" I mean it didn't appear, I'll debug this further).

I know I didn't provide much detailed code but that's because I mainly want to know what's the general principle of how it should be done. I want to know why the cell doesn't stay with the `selected` property equal to `YES` even though it stays blue (when `selectionStyle` is the default one) when I tap it. I want it to stay "blue"(selected) with that view inside it until I deselect it and remove said view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try creating your own custom `UITableViewCell`? I think that is the point, you can overload `setSelected:` method there.

Comment: I didn't, I have been trying to avoid subclassing but I'll definitely do it if I can't find any other way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed NR4TR's advice and so far so good. I have subclassed UITableViewCell and have overridden the setSelected method in it.

Hoping this is useful to someone else in the future!